# NSSortDescriptor Removing Items From Array For No Apparant Reason

Tags: ios, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I've got two arrays which are being sorted based on the one with a various number of `NSNumber` objects.
When I come to sort it, the returned array of names has had one of it's items removed - why would this be?! Code:

```
NSDictionary *temp = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:self.names forKeys:self.times];
            NSSortDescriptor *theDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(compare:)];
            self.times = [[temp allKeys] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:theDescriptor]];
            self.names = [temp objectsForKeys:self.finishedTimes notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`? Can you show us the input data set and explain why you think an item has been removed?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tommy - the issue still occurs after using sortedArrayUsingSelector unfortunately. I know an item has been removed as I'm logging before and after it being processed, and an item is being removed :P Would any other solutions come to mind?

Comment: Can you show us the input data set, the method you're using to log and the output you're seeing?

Comment: I'm using NSLong @Tommy. The input Data set is Name 1, Name 2, and Name 3 + Time 1, Time 2, and Time 3. After the filtering it returns: Name 1, Name 2 + Time 1, and Time 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following:

```
NSDictionary *temp =
@{
    @"Name 2" : @"Time 2",
    @"Name 1" : @"Time 1",
    @"Name 3" : @"Time 3",
};

NSArray *times = [[temp allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog(@"Names: %@", [temp objectsForKeys:times notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]]);
```

Output was as expected:

```
2015-12-17 10:37:52.879 Test[6503:273457] Names: (
    "Time 1",
    "Time 2",
    "Time 3"
)
```

NSArray does not remove items when sorting; your problem is in some of the code you're not disclosing.